# Redux State is changing but App.js not re-rendering

Tags: javascript, reactjs, redux

I am new to the concept of Redux, Just trying to add a className to a div in App.js when the redux state change.

```
const menuToggle = useSelector((state) => state.menuToggle);
    
 <div className="App">
     <div className={`layout-wrapper ${menuToggle ? 'toggled' : ''}`}>
         <div className="layout-container">
```

Redux State is getting change
[image]

when menuToggle turns true then the className is getting added. But when it is updating as false the App.js not re-rendering.

[image]

Can anybody tell me what I am missing?

Comment: I'm also new to Redux, but I think you need to dispatch a `specific` action so that Redux can update the state you want.

Comment: Are you using a `useMemo` hook? Is `menuToggle` in the dependency array?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think your state shape is not right.

What you have is:

```
{
   // other state
   menuToggle: {
       menuToggle: false // or true
   }
}
```

Since you then access `state.menuToggle` it will return an object and not a bool, and objects are truthy. When you flip the (now nested `state.menuToggle.menuToggle`) property back to `false` it doesn't matter because `state.menuToggle` is still an object, and therefore truthy.  You might wonder why it flips the first time -- it's probably because your initial state is the right shape, and it's the toggle action/reducer that then breaks this state by changing it to have an additional layer of nesting.

In short it *is* rerendering, but the value being read isn't the one you think it is and once the toggle action is triggered, that read value is forever stuck on a truthy value.

You probably meant for the state to always stay in this shape consistently:

```
{
   // other state
   menuToggle: false // or true
}
```

To fix you could change your selector to `state.menuToggle.menuToggle` but I think the real fix is to fix the bug in your reducer or action that is incorrectly setting the state shape. But you'd need to post those to help further.

Answer (score 0):

Make sure that you have your Redux store configured and scoped properly.

Here is a [CodeSandbox demo](https://codesandbox.io/s/wonderful-maxwell-0nxfhb) of the application below.

### index.jsx

```
import { StrictMode } from "react";
import { createRoot } from "react-dom/client";
import { Provider } from "react-redux";
import { store } from "./store";
import App from "./App";

const rootElement = document.getElementById("root");
const root = createRoot(rootElement);

root.render(
  <StrictMode>
    <Provider store={store}>
      <App />
    </Provider>
  </StrictMode>
);
```

### App.jsx

```
import "./styles.css";
import { useCallback } from "react";
import { useDispatch, useSelector } from "react-redux";
import { toggleMenu } from "./appSlice";

const App = () => {
  const dispatch = useDispatch();
  const { menuToggle } = useSelector((state) => state.app); // appReducer (via store)

  const onToggle = useCallback(() => {
    dispatch(toggleMenu());
  }, [dispatch]);

  return (
    <div className="App">
      <button onClick={onToggle}>{menuToggle ? "Hide" : "Show"}</button>
      {menuToggle && <h2 className="card">Hello World</h2>}
    </div>
  );
};

export default App;
```

### appSlice.jsx

```
import { createSlice } from "@reduxjs/toolkit";

const appSlice = createSlice({
  name: "app",
  initialState: {
    menuToggle: false
  },
  reducers: {
    openMenu(state) {
      state.menuToggle = true;
    },
    closeMenu(state) {
      state.menuToggle = false;
    },
    toggleMenu(state) {
      state.menuToggle = !state.menuToggle;
    }
  }
});

export const { closeMenu, openMenu, toggleMenu } = appSlice.actions;
export default appSlice.reducer;
```

### store.jsx

```
import { configureStore } from "@reduxjs/toolkit";
import appReducer from "./appSlice";

const store = configureStore({
  reducer: {
    app: appReducer
  }
});

export { store };
```

### styles.css

```css
.App {
  font-family: sans-serif;
  text-align: center;
}

.card {
  border: thin solid grey;
  border-radius: 1rem;
  padding: 1rem;
}
```